# Data table integrated with Angular not showing export buttons such as Excel, PDF

Tags: jquery, angular, jquery-plugins, datatables, angular-datatables

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "../node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css",
    "../node_modules/datatables.net-buttons-dt/css/buttons.dataTables.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
    "../node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.js",
    "../node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.colVis.js",
    "../node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.flash.js",
    "../node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.js",
    "../node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.js",   
 ],
```

This is the angular-cli.json I have created file for my project.

Component for the project looks like this;

```
ngOnInit() {
this.dtOptions = {
  pagingType: 'full_numbers',
  pageLength: 10,
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: [
    'copy', 'print', 'csv','columnsToggle','colvis','pdf','excel']    
  };
  this.loadapi();
}
```

Here I have created a datatable from a sample json. Every thing was fine except the button to export excel and pdf didn't show other buttons are showing on UI. What may be the issue?

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 6):

Please Follow steps:

1: Install its dependencies:

```
npm install jszip --save
npm install datatables.net-buttons --save
npm install datatables.net-buttons-dt --save
```

2:Add the dependencies in the scripts and styles attributes:

```
    {
  "projects": {
    "your-app-name": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "styles": [
              ...
              "node_modules/datatables.net-buttons-dt/css/buttons.dataTables.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              ...
              "node_modules/jszip/dist/jszip.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.colVis.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.flash.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.js"
            ],
            ...
}
```

If you want to have the excel export functionnality, then you must import the jszip.js before the buttons.html5.js file.

3:HTML:

```
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="row-border hover"></table>
```

4:DtOptions in Typescript:

```
        this.dtOptions = {
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: [
        'copy',
        'print',
        'csv',
        'excel',
        'pdf'
      ]
    };
```

For more help refer this [link](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/extensions/buttons).

Comment: Funcionó perfecto..!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.. but in my case none of the buttons were coming up.. so, in addition to the other steps in https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/extensions/buttons,

I had to import them in my specific file.. (I needed only the CSV button)

```
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.colVis.min';
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min';
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.flash.min';
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.min';
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Which specific file?I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  It's probably because you're also using page length.

Try this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.dtOptions = {
    pagingType: 'full_numbers',
    pageLength: 10,
    dom: 'Blfrtip', // Use 'Blfrtip' instead of 'Bfrtip'
    buttons: [
      'copy', 'print', 'csv','columnsToggle','colvis','pdf','excel']    
  };
  this.loadapi();
}
```

This also works, but it doesn't look like you're really doing much with the page length (in terms of allowing one to change the length), so it might not be ideal for you. However, it might be useful to someone else:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.dtOptions = {
    pagingType: 'full_numbers',
    pageLength: 10,
    dom: 'Bfrtip', 
    // Use the pageLength button
    buttons: [
      'pageLength', 'copy', 'print', 'csv','columnsToggle','colvis','pdf','excel']    
  };
  this.loadapi();
}
```

You have more options, but these two are the simplest that I can think of.

Source: https://datatables.net/reference/button/pageLength