# Data table in angular does not show export buttons

Tags: angular, datatable, export-to-excel

I am using `datatable` in Angular 12. I have integrated all the features of datatable in my application and they are working fine.

I added export buttons functionality but I can not see any export buttons in my DOM. They are not rendered for some reason. I have tried [this StackOverflow question as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49322350/data-table-integrated-with-angular-not-showing-export-buttons-such-as-excel-pdf) but it is not helping at all.

This is my code:

**angular.json**

[image: anglar.json]

**TS file**

[image: TS file]

**HTML code**

[image: Html file]

**End results**
[image: Dom results]

I have tried many things, any help will be appreciated